# Audiogram code in Python

Tags: python-2.7, audio, signal-processing

I'm writing a code of an audiogram.

Here's the code.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pyaudio

freqs =[0.0, 125.0,1000.0,2000.0,3000.0,4000.0, 5000.0, 6000.0, 7000.0, 8000.0]
p = pyaudio.PyAudio()
stream = p.open(format=pyaudio.paFloat32,
                channels=1,
                rate=44100,
                output=True)


def play_freqs():

    volume = 0.1
    duration = 1.0  # in seconds, may be float
    fs = 44100  # sampling rate, Hz, must be integer


    print "===> Starting audiometric test"
    i = 0

    points = [] #when plotting this is x axis
    volumes = [] #when plotting this is y axis

    while i<10:
        if i == 0:
            volume = 0.1
            samples = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(fs * duration) * freqs[i] / fs)).astype(np.float32)
            stream.write(volume * samples)

        x = raw_input('T/F') #it should continue until sounds of all frequencies from the list are played

        if x == 'f':
               while True: #it should make unlimited amount of iterations but when it comes across the condition if below; it should stop and continue with x = raw_input
                   volume = volume + 0.1
                   samples = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(fs * duration) * freqs[i] / fs)).astype(np.float32)
                   stream.write(volume*samples)
                   if volume == 1.0:
                       np.append(points, freqs[i])
                       np.append(volumes, float(volume))
                       break

        if x == 't':
                volume = 0.1
                samples = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(fs * duration) * freqs[i] / fs)).astype(np.float32)
                stream.write(volume * samples)
                np.append(points, freqs[i])
                np.append(volumes, float(volume))
                i = i + 1 #it should continue with the next element from list freqs


def plot_signal(self, x,y):
    plt.plot(np.array(x),np.array(y),'o')
    plt.gca().invert_yaxis()
    plt.show()
    print "Finished"


play_freqs()
stream.stop_stream()
stream.close()
p.terminate()
```

Now the problems:

1. When it enters the while loop when x == 'f'; it doesn't come out of it.
2. I'd like the if conditions to be checked with each iteration. What I mean by this is when x e.g. is 'f': the sound should be volumed up; let's say somebody's completely deaf at this frequency, so it should volume up the sound until it reaches volume of 1.0. Then it should prompt x.rawinput.

When x == t, it should play the sound, append it to the list, and again prompt the x.rawinput.

The even if the patient didn't hear the sound with all volumes it should move on to the next frequency, giving a chance to analyse other sounds. x.rawinput should continu until all the frequencies are done.

Please let me know, what are the problems with my code, because unfortunately it gets stuck in the middle of the loop. I don't neccessary need a direct solution, rather a hint what I'm doing wrong.

THANKS A LOT!

Leah

Comment: Please include additional information directly in your question and not in the comments. Simply edit your question and post the information there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your iterator 'i' only bumps up if 'x' == t. Surely you want it to bump up at the end of each round of checks, and therefore move it up in scope?

So:

```
 while i<10:
        if i == 0:
            volume = 0.1
            samples = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(fs * duration) * freqs[i] / fs)).astype(np.float32)
            stream.write(volume * samples)

        x = raw_input('T/F') #it should continue until sounds of all frequencies from the list are played

        if x == 'f':
               while True: #it should make unlimited amount of iterations but when it comes across the condition if below; it should stop and continue with x = raw_input
                   volume = volume + 0.1
                   samples = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(fs * duration) * freqs[i] / fs)).astype(np.float32)
                   stream.write(volume*samples)
                   if volume == 1.0:
                       np.append(points, freqs[i])
                       np.append(volumes, float(volume))
                       break

        if x == 't':
                volume = 0.1
                samples = (np.sin(2 * np.pi * np.arange(fs * duration) * freqs[i] / fs)).astype(np.float32)
                stream.write(volume * samples)
                np.append(points, freqs[i])
                np.append(volumes, float(volume))


        i = i + 1 #it should continue with the next element from list freqs
```